# How do I import a 3D model in unity scene using c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I import a 3D model ion unity scene using c#?

Comment: By typing the script. and then showing us what you typed, then we can help you with your code, stackoverflow is not a code generator

Comment: Is ion a particular framework, or a typo? You can never tell these days...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not asking you to write the code. I just wanted to ask any reference or if there are any command or 2 because I couldn't find one that works since morning. And I would like to make it clear that my software does not only consist of these lines. Thanks again

Comment: @code11 it is a type. I meant to say. in the scene.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to "import" your model into your scene, but you will be able to instantiate a Unity Prefab, containing your 3D model. The prefab acts as a template from which you can create new object instances in the scene, containing every component you want (MeshRenderer with your 3D model for instance)

Take a look at the documentation :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

```
// Unityscript
// Drag & Drop your prefab in this field inside the inspector
var brick : Transform;

function Start () {
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            Instantiate(brick, Vector3 (x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// C#
// Drag & Drop your prefab in this field inside the inspector
public Transform brick;

void Start() {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            Instantiate(brick, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```